# How do I detect 'space' in a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, keypress

I am creating a text based game and in order to speed past dialogue I want the user to be able to hit 'Space' and skip past it.

```
import time
import sys

text_speed = .05

def slow_type(line, speed): #You input the dialogue and speed(smaller = faster)
    for l in line:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(speed)
    time.sleep(.5)

if <'Space'> pressed:
    text_speed = 0

NL1 = "Huh, I see you finally came. "

slow_type(NL1, text_speed)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

Here is a sample code to detect space, also note that the code will wait for space key to be pressed.

```
import keyboard

#.....

if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
    text_speed = 0

#....
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python representation of a space is `u"\u0020"`, referred [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm).

And tested with:

```
if input('enter:') == u"\u0020":
    print('pass')
else:
    print('fail')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) module.

```
import getch
while getch.getch() != ' ':
    pass
```

Or on Windows, you can use `msvcr.getch`:

```
import msvcrt
while msvcrt.getch() != ' ':
    pass
```